# How to print the elements of a tuple sided by side

Tags: python-3.x

I am able to print the elements one after the another but I want the result to be printed side by side: 1234, instead of:
1
2
3
4

Display which I am getting

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

The code is to display 7 segment led display.

```
led_dict={
    '0':('###','# #','# #','# #','###'),
    '1':('  #','  #','  #','  #','  #'),
    '2':('###','  #','###','#  ','###'),
    '3':('###','  #','###','  #','###'),
    '4':('# #','# #','###','  #','  #'),
    '5':('###','#  ','###','  #','###'),
    '6':('###','#  ','###','# #','###'),
    '7':('###','  #','  #','  #','  #'),
    '8':('###','# #','###','# #','###'),
    '9':('###','# #','###','  #','###')
    }

x = input('Enter a number to be displayed: ')

d_list=[]

for num in str(x):
    d_list.append(led_dict[num])
print(d_list)
# for i in range(5):
#     for ab in d_list:
#         print(ab[i])

for ab in d_list:
    for i in range(5):
        print((ab[i]))
```

Comment: I want to display it as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(' '.join(k[i] for k in d_list))
```

How it works;

Each number tuple consists of five lines.
But we have to print by line. That means we have to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the same elements of the tuple for all digits, and then print the resulting string. If we do that five times, (see the index `i`) we will have printed the whole number.

An example:

```
Python 3.9.9 (main, Dec 11 2021, 14:34:11) 
>>> led_dict={'0': ('###', '# #', '# #', '# #', '###'),
...  '1': ('  #', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'),
...  '2': ('###', '  #', '###', '#  ', '###'),
...  '3': ('###', '  #', '###', '  #', '###'),
...  '4': ('# #', '# #', '###', '  #', '  #'),
...  '5': ('###', '#  ', '###', '  #', '###'),
...  '6': ('###', '#  ', '###', '# #', '###'),
...  '7': ('###', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'),
...  '8': ('###', '# #', '###', '# #', '###'),
...  '9': ('###', '# #', '###', '  #', '###')}
>>> d_list=[]
>>> for num in '3427':
...     d_list.append(led_dict[num])
... 
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(' '.join(k[i] for k in d_list))
... 
### # # ### ###
  # # #   #   #
### ### ###   #
  #   # #     #
###   # ###   #
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not get this part: 'print(' '.join(k[i] for k in d_list))' , could you please elaborate a bit.Thanks

Comment: @PraveenPaliwal See updated answer.

Comment: Great! Than you so much for the explanation @Roland Smith

Comment: Hi @Roland Smith, Sorry to bother you again, I thought I understood it , to some part I did, but to me the last part looks like a rule, is it possible to simplify it further, maybe without using list comprehension.

Comment: @PraveenPaliwal I'm not using a list comprehension. The argument to the `join` is a [generator expression](https://pycon2019.trey.io/generator-expressions.html), a kind of iterator.  But you could make another for-loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
led_dict={
    '0':('###','# #','# #','# #','###'),
    '1':('  #','  #','  #','  #','  #'),
    '2':('###','  #','###','#  ','###'),
    '3':('###','  #','###','  #','###'),
    '4':('# #','# #','###','  #','  #'),
    '5':('###','#  ','###','  #','###'),
    '6':('###','#  ','###','# #','###'),
    '7':('###','  #','  #','  #','  #'),
    '8':('###','# #','###','# #','###'),
    '9':('###','# #','###','  #','###')
    }

x = input('Enter a number to be displayed: ')

d_list=[]  
for num in str(x):
    d_list.append(led_dict[num])

for i in range(5):
    for ab in d_list:
        print(ab[i],end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Note that this has an extra space at the end of each line. But it would work just fine. *In general*, using comprehensions and generators is considered "more Pythonic". For large amount of data, generators use less memory than list comprehensions, and are faster than for-loops. (Not an issue in this case, just for your information.)